# Textbook for CNN-LSTM networks of predictions of numerical data

Tags: resource-request, books

I am learning NN algorithms because I'd like to create my own project.
What I found on the internet, is that for my type of project which I have in mind CNN-LSTM neural network would be ideal.

But now I have a question - I don't know if it's against the rules of this forum or not. So pardon me if I violated them.

So, now I am learning NN algorithms from a couple of books that "classify" them like: Classification NN, LSTM, Convolutional - each neural network is a separate topic in each book.

But I am looking for a book that teaches the reader about Convolutional Long-Short Term Memory Neural Network. Does someone know such a book where such hybrid NN is the main topic?

Comment: Hello, welcome to AI stack exchange. Asking for textbooks related to AI is on-topic here. So, no need to worry about this question. Read [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details.

Comment: I edited the tile of your question, please re-edit if you are not comfortable with it.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to find a textbook that contains all hybrid neural networks. Since the field is changing so frequently, even if someone writes a book about it, it will likely become obsolete in a few years.

There is actually a nice paper (with lots of citation) that developed the network you mentioned:
[Convolutional LSTM Network: A Machine Learning
Approach for Precipitation Nowcasting](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2015/file/07563a3fe3bbe7e3ba84431ad9d055af-Paper.pdf)

You are more likely to find different kinds of neural network architectures in journal or conference papers. Hope this helps!